# Magento 2 : run multi query on upgrade database

Tags: magento2, database

For upgrade database, I use direct SQL such as belove code

```
 $setup->run("delete from directory_country_region");

            $setup->run("TRUNCATE directory_country_region");

            $setup->run("delete from directory_country_region_city");

            $setup->run("TRUNCATE directory_country_region_city");
```

but just last query was executed.

Answer (score 0):

i do like this ... i do not know why it is worked but it's worked

```
    $setup->startSetup();

    $setup->run("delete from directory_country_region_city");
    $setup->startSetup();

    $setup->run("TRUNCATE directory_country_region_city");
    $setup->startSetup();


    $setup->run("delete from directory_country_region_name");
    $setup->startSetup();

    $setup->run("TRUNCATE directory_country_region_name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use method chaining to run multiple queries when doing schema setup. Like this:

```
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("delete from directory_country_region_city")
->run("TRUNCATE directory_country_region_city")
->run("delete from directory_country_region_name");
```